# beginner with linear approximations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

So I am just learning about linear approximations in my class. But I just don't understand how to figure out the a[image]nswer. Can someone please explain it in more detail to me thanks.

Comment: Sure you must have studied lately Taylor polynomial and stuff, right? Or perhaps the differential?

Comment: I'm not asking for the answer, I'm asking for a better explanation because I don't understand it.

Comment: @Bye_World i do not understand how to use it

Comment: @rick, and I was asking you what've you studied as otherwise it is very hard to know how to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The linear approximation at a point is just the line tangent to the graph at the given point. This is given by $$L(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0).$$

The way to find this is the usual point slope formula, recalling that the slope of the tangent line at $x_0$ is $f'(x_0)$. (This is somewhat the definition of tangent)

Now, your function is $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 + x}$. the derivative is easy to compute rewriting $\sqrt[3]{1 + x} = (1 + x)^{1/3}$, hence $g'(x) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(1 + x)^2}}$.

Now all you need to do is plug in everything in the first formula I gave you:
$$L(x) = g(0) + g'(0)(x - 0) = 1 + \frac{x}{3}.$$

The two values you are looking for are $L(-0.05)$ and $L(0.1)$.

I hope this cleared things out a little bit!